# Differentiate $T(z)=(az+b)/(cz+d)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the derivative of the function $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, where
>   $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{C}$ with $ad - bc \neq 0$. When is $T'(z) = 0$?

Just want to check that this problem is analogous to what we do in real analysis. The quotient rule gives

$$T'(z)=\frac{a(cz+d)-c(az+b)}{(cz+d)^2}=\frac{ad-bc}{(cz+d)^2},$$

Thus the derivative of $T$ is zero iff $ad-bc=0.$ However this is excluded in the problem. So what do they want me to realise here?

Comment: That's not what I get for $T'(z)$.

Comment: Neither did I really. Typo in my calculations. Edited. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: You could always let $z$ tend to infinity...

Comment: How do I motivate that? its like saying that $\frac{\infty}{\infty}=0.$ Also, what does it mean for a complex number to go to infinity really?

Answer (score 1):

If $ad-bc=0$ then $(a,b)$ is a multiple $(c,d)$, hence $T$ is constant. If $ad-bc\neq 0$ then $T'(z)$ is never zero as you proved. It folows that $T$ is a local biholomorphism by the (holomorphic) inverse function theorem. In fact, it is a global biholomorphism since the injectivity can be easily checked.

Answer (score 1):

$T'(z)\neq 0$ for $z\neq -\frac{d}{c}$ or $\infty$. For $z=-\frac{d}{c}$ (in which case
$T(z) =\infty$) it is easily checked that $\psi'(z)\neq 0$, where $\psi(z) = \frac{1}{T(z)}$, and for $z=\infty$ it is easily checked that $T'(1/z)\neq 0$.

So $T(z)$ (Mobius transformation) is conformal at every point of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: So what is the actually condition for "conformality"? Is it that $T'(1/z)\neq 0?$ And what does this mean?

Comment: A conformal map is a function that preserves angles locally.  If $U$ is an open subset of the complex plane $\Bbb{C}$ , then a function $f:U\to \Bbb C$ is conformal if and only if it is holomorphic and its derivative is everywhere non-zero on $U$.